# Does PartitionKey and RowKey in Azure Table Storage have to be string?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I suspect so, as the abstract class TableServiceEntity have the following:

```
    public virtual string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string RowKey { get; set; }
```

What if I want a RowKey that is a DateTime or a Double?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

yes, these are both strings.

If you want the RowKey to be a DateTime or a Double then you must use a string representation.

There are a few common patterns for this. For DateTime, it's common to see the DateTime represented using a string that is conveniently sorted:

- DateTime.Ticks.ToString("d19")

or

- (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.Ticks).ToString("d19")

See this blog post from Steve Marx - http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-numbers-as-keys-in-windows-azure

Comment: I also found this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338.aspx) that is definitive. **The partition key may be a string value up to 1 KB in size.** Also: **The row key is a string value that may be up to 1 KB in size.**

Comment: Also please note there are 4 banned characters - \,/,?,# (I think) - if you use these then you'll get an "out of range" type error message

Comment: Will this then take advantage of the fact that the data should be partitioned daily or hourly etc? How would one do greater than or between queries if it is a string?